# My function keeps returning old editions of my variable even though I only want the latest

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function that asks the user for some input and performs some checks on the input. If the input is not according to several criteria, it runs the function again and asks the user again for some input.

However, when I then return the function it returns both the latest input, but also the incorrect input. What am I doing wrong? Some of the print statements are purely for debugging

```
def get_email(email):
    print('starting email is',email)
    while email == 'empty':
        print('the email we use now is',email)
        email = input()
        print("your input email is",email)
    if '@' not in email:
        get_email('empty')
    elif email[-1] == '@':
        get_email('empty')
    elif email[0] == '@':
        get_email('empty')
    print("the email we return is",email)
    return email
get_email('empty')
```

Comment: either use `input()` to get the email or use it as an argument for the function, not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing recursion in two ways: first, you aren't using the return value of the recursive call:

```
def get_email(email):
    print('starting email is',email)
    while email == 'empty':
        print('the email we use now is',email)
        email = input()
        print("your input email is",email)
    if '@' not in email:
        email = get_email('empty')
    elif email[-1] == '@':
        email = get_email('empty')
    elif email[0] == '@':
        email = get_email('empty')
    print("the email we return is",email)
    return email

print(get_email('empty'))
```

Second, you shouldn't be using recursion at all in Python if a simple loop will suffice.

```
def get_email(email):
    print('starting email is', email)
    # @ isn't in 'empty', so no need to check for empty specifically
    while '@' not in email or email[-1] == '@' or email[0] == '@':
        print('the email we use now is ', email)
        email = input()
        print('your input email is ', email)
    print('the email we return is ', email)
    return email
```